# imported class not recognized in delegate file ios 7.0

Tags: objective-c, import, delegates

Here is my code:

//
//  mapViewControllerDelegate.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "mapViewController.h"

@protocol mapViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)mapViewControllerClickedDoneButton:(mapViewController*)map;

@end
```

I get error "unrecognized type", wondering why. Probably something really basic, sorry.

Comment: #import "MapViewController.h" ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the delegate property of self to a value